# type 'Future<void>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have looked for similar answers and tried using their proposed solutions with no success. I am trying to build a dropdown with data from the dynamic. Every time I try to run it, it gives me a
"type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'" and I am using Getx framework in flutter

Answer (score 0):

If you had code then it would easy to pinpoint the issue. Basically you are returning nothing from your function that is its return type is Future and calling that function for some parameter that expects to receive a widget. So your function should return some class that extends statelessWidget or statefulWidget.

Hope makes sense.